# Blocking and deleting e-mail

Tags: linux, email, exim, spamassassin, assp

I have a server running EXIM and I was wondering if there was a way to block e-mail from going out should a member load over 1000 e-mails in to the queue and then automatically delete them.

Comment: I am no Exim expert but one idea is to use Exim's rate limiting features and a custom ACL that runs a custom script to purge all email from the offending user.

Comment: Yea, true. Just was wondering if there would be a way to just prevent the small trickle of abuse if so many got loaded into que